# MVC - pass data from input to view with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url.action

I have simply view:

```
<input type="text" id="wprowadz" name="imie"/>
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Wynik", "Home", new { name = name })'" />
```

And i need pass text from input to controller:

```
public string Wynik(string name)
    {
        return name;

    }
```

i was search on tons of sites - i found this but it's not working - i got error on second "name" in view... what im doing wrong...

Comment: Why are you using `location.href` in an `onclick` handler instead of just having that button submit a form?  That seems to be the root of the problem here.  Just wrapping your input and button in a form and having the button submit the form would be simpler.

Comment: Wrap this inside a form and set name attribute equal to "name" . You will get the value in the controller..

Comment: because @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Wynik", "Home", new { name = "name" }) not working...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be over-complicating this by involving JavaScript at all.  If you just want an input, a button, and to post that value to the server then what you want is a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Wynik", "Home")
{
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Upon clicking the "Create" button, the form is submitted to the `Wynik` controller action with a string in the `name` parameter.